# Alfresco creating PDF rendition from PPTX File

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm POSTing to `/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/c31b9572-7d9e-4b50-a2ae-62b69c156cd3/renditions` with the body `{"id":"pdf"}` and getting a 400 error back:

```
{"error":{"errorKey":"Unable to create thumbnail 'pdf' for application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation as no transformer is currently available.","statusCode":400,"briefSummary":"09170006 Unable to create thumbnail 'pdf' for application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation as no transformer is currently available.","stackTrace":"For security reasons the stack trace is no longer displayed, but the property is kept for previous versions","descriptionURL":"https://api-explorer.alfresco.com"}}
```

Basically, saying there's no transformer available

At `/alfresco/service/mimetypes?mimetype=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation#application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`

It lists the following:

```
application/eps = Complex via: application/pdf
application/pdf = Using JOD Converter / Open Office
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint = Using JOD Converter / Open Office
```

So, my question is if the transformer shows as available...why is the request to generate the rendition failing?

Here's the relevant parts of `alfresco-global.properties`

```
ooo.enabled=false
jodconverter.enabled=true
jodconverter.officeHome=/opt/libreoffice6.2
...
alfresco-pdf-renderer.root=/opt/alfresco/bin
alfresco-pdf-renderer.exe=${alfresco-pdf-renderer.root}/alfresco-pdf-renderer
#Shell script to limit cpu used by ImageMagick convert. Edit to match your number of cpu:s
img.exe=/opt/alfresco/scripts/limitconvert.sh
img.root=/etc/ImageMagick
img.dyn=/usr/lib
...
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xlsm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.pptm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xls.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=10240
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.sldm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xltx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.potx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.docx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xlsx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=10240
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.pptx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.ppt.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xlam.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.docm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xltm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.dotx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.xlsb.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.sldx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.ppsm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.potm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.txt.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.ppam.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.dotm.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.doc.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.vsd.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.ppsx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=50000
```

Comment: If you go to the admin console at `/alfresco/` then check transformers, what's the state of the jod converter one?

Comment: I guess either your jodconverter is not working or you hit the maxSourceSizeKBytes limit.

Comment: @Gagravarr jod converter is online. And I've set the maxSourceSizeKBytes limit to something outrageous, 1GB

Comment: What ends up in the `alfresco.log` file when you try the transformation?